# 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I am now working on a MVC project on running the program I've got an error on trying to retrieve the data from my SqlServer Database.

**Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Activity.Models;

namespace Activity.Controllers
{
     public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ProductDetails(int id)
        {
            ProductContext productsContext = new ProductContext();
            Products prod = productsContext.Product.Single(pru => pru.ProductKey == id);

            return View(prod);
        }

    }
}
```

**Models:** I have two classes(Products.cs and ProductContext.cs)

***For ProductContext.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Activity.Models
{
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Products> Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***For Products.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Activity.Models
{

    [Table("PruProductDetails")]
    public class Products
    {
        public int ProductKey { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Discountable { get; set; }
        public string DateAdded { get; set; }
        public double Discount { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int ReOrderLevel { get; set; }
        public int OrderLimit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProductContext"
         connectionString="server=(local); database=Exam; integrated security=SSPI"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
```

**Global.asax**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Activity
{

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Activity.Models.ProductContext>(null);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
 }
```

I hope someone can help me. I am only a beginner in MVC. Thank you

Comment: What are the details of the error, and on which line of code it it thrown?

Comment: Hi Sir. The error is in this part "Products prod = productsContext.Product.Single(pru => pru.ProductKey == id);" of my Controller.

Comment: please try adding try catch suggest in this link, doing so will show you the actual exception message and then could resolve the issue easily.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777004/modelvalidationexception-was-unhandled-user-code

Comment: Also try adding [Key] attribute for your ProductKey property of your product class and see if the issue gets resolves

Comment: {"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nActivity.Models.Products: : EntityType 'Products' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nProduct: EntityType: EntitySet 'Product' is based on type 'Products' that has no keys defined.\r\n"}

Comment: wher do i put the [Key] Sir?

Comment: public class Products
    { [Key]
        public int ProductKey { get; set; }

Comment: To avoid more comments, posted the answer, please respond me over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your Products class like this - Adding Key attribute for ProductKey

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Activity.Models
{

[Table("PruProductDetails")]
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductKey { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Discountable { get; set; }
    public string DateAdded { get; set; }
    public double Discount { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ReOrderLevel { get; set; }
    public int OrderLimit { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Sir. I already fixed it. the [Key] helped a lot. Thank you :D

Comment: Just wanted to know for curiosity, did you unmark my Answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am also having same kind of error The solution is really simple your name of properties should be matched with sql server columns and one more important thing syntax of writing:
more important thing syntax of writing:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) {
  EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
  Employee employee = employeecontext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.Employeeid == id);
  return View(employee);


  public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee employee = employeecontext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.Employeeid == id);

            return View(employee);
        }
```

int the following code you have to write int id if you write any variable instead of int id then you will get an error I hope my solution of this error should be helpful