# Entinty Framework saving context with null fields mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is object Image

```
public int Id { get; }           //primary key
public string Path { get; set; } //not null
public string Name { get; set; } //not null
public string Url { get; set; }  //allows null
public string SecureUrl { get; set; } //allows null
```

EFDbImageRepository

```
public void UploadToCloud(Image image)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(image.Id);
    if(image.Id == 0)
    {
        context.Images.Add(image);
    }else
    {
        Image dbEntry = context.Images.Find(image.Id);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In controller in the UploadImage action

```
 ...   
 Image image = new Image();
 image.init(path, "defaultName1", "type");
 imageRepository.UploadToCloud(image);
 ...
```

At moment UploadToCloud I have en exception:
`'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' in EntityFramework.dll`

It seems that there is a problem with data, that I try to save, but I don't understand what is wrong. At this moment I initialize only 2 fields Path and Name. Id should be set automatically, Url and SecureUrl allows null, so all should be good.

How to save object to database?

Comment: Add the [Key] attribute above public int Id { get; }  and try

Comment: You have to look at the ValidationExceptions collection to see what is wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777004/modelvalidationexception-was-unhandled-user-code how to do that,

Comment: Moreover, your update code is not working. Assigning an entity to `dbEntry` will not cause it to update. Please read the tutorials again about how to update entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the `Id` field readonly. Entity frameworke ignores readonly properties, so you have now created an entity *without* a primary key. You have at least to add `private set`, but why no ordinary (public) `{get;set;}`?.